# What's the definition of ACTL?

Tags: model-checking, temporal-logic

I have been looking for the definition of ACTL, but Google has given me very little to go with.

So far, I know ACTL is another form of CTL model checking, and CTL includes the following operators:

- Always
- Exist
- Global
- Finally
- Next
- AND / OR
- NOT

So what does ACTL include and how is it different from CTL?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ACTL is the universal fragment of CTL.
Thus, existential path quantification is not allowed. 
So a path formula is of the form $AF\psi$,  $AG\psi$, or $AX\psi$ (or a conjunction or disjunction of path formulas).

Moreover, you are not allowed a general NOT operator, but rather negations have to be on the atomic propositions (otherwise this fragment would be equal to CTL).

Comment: so E operator is not allowed, but can you give an example for the second part with NOT operator?

Comment: You can't write $\neg AGp$, since it's equivalent to $EF\neg p$, so you get an $E$ operator. Negations are only allowed on the inner proposition, e.g. $AG\neg p$.

Comment: that was so much easier to understand than reading through article on Google. Thank heaps, Shaull

Comment: So how does ACTL differ from LTL, given that LTL formulas can be thought of as having an implicit A in front of them?

Comment: @N.S. ACTL is weaker than LTL: an LTL formula can say something like FGp (or, with the explicit quantifier: AFGp), which means "all paths must have finitely many $\neg p$". This cannot be captured in CTL (requires proof), because intuitively you can only say something like AFAGp, meaning that in all paths you eventually reach a state from which all paths always labelled p. But this is a stronger requirement, as it implies a "uniform" bound on the eventuality.